# Modify object to take in another parameter

Tags: angular

I have the following object that I am trying to modify. I want it to have 2 parameters

```
public headers: any[],
```

I want the above to have 2 parameters called `colName` and `tableFilter`

Then I want to be able to use it in another file

```
  headerData = { headers: ['', '', ''] };

  this.headerData = {
       headers: [ 
                 {"A", true},
                 {"B", true},
                 {"C", true}
                ]
  };
```

I tried something like this `public headers: [{'colName': any, 'tableFilter': boolean }],` but not sure it is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type should be

```
public headers: {colName: any, tableFilter: boolean }[]
```

Or

```
public headers: Array<{colName: any, tableFilter: boolean }>
```